# Changing Bundle Identifier causes "Could not find a storyboard named 'Main'

Tags: ios, xcode

Funny thing is, I'v never used a storyboard in this project.

Restoring Bundle ID to the original one fixes the issue. 
I'v tried the usual cleaning build, restarting Xcode, reinstalling app on the device/simulator - nothing.

I'v seen a lot of questions connected to this error, 
but they all had to do with to ether the Storyboard file, 
or the localisation options, with I don't use at all.

Comment: Look at the Info.plist for a main storyboard setting and delete it.

Comment: Did that, caused app to just display black screen after launch.

Comment: Thus proving that you _are_ using a storyboard after all. Your interface was always in that storyboard, and when you remove the designation of that storyboard as your main storyboard, your interface goes away.

Comment: And yet there is literally no *.storyboard file, I went through the entire project, and even my backups - storyboard never existed, I'm sure of it.

Comment: I'm curious how you changed the bundle id. What exact action did this involve?

Comment: Oh, and while I'm peppering you with questions :) if you are not using a storyboard where do you think your interface is _supposed_ to come from?

Comment: 1. Targets -> My Project -> Info -> Bundle identifier 2.Project was created from an Empty Application template. View Controller sets up and displays the SKScene (from Sprite Kit framework) - thats my interface.

Comment: But you didn't use the SpriteKit Game template?

Comment: No, I did not. Now that I think about it I have no idea what executes the ViewController in the first place - since its not bound to storyboard. I guess I will create a new storyboard, connect it to the ViewController, and see what happens.

Comment: So how does the View Controller's view get into the interface?

Comment: Exactly. If you just used the Empty Application and you didn't explicitly create the view controller and put its view into the interface, then it was never getting into the interface that way.

Comment: Moreover, if you were using the Empty Application template, how did the Info.plist come to be referring to a main storyboard? It doesn't come like that, I assure you.

Comment: Seems that I was wrong, it must have been the SK Game Template, sory about that. I feel kinda silly now. I assumed it was an Empty template because thats what was written in the guide I used (guide to basics of SK), but I guess I went with Game template at same point (it was a while ago). Still no idea why the storyboard was missing, or why only after changing bundle ID did Xcode realised it was gone, but no matter - my mistake. Thanks for pointing out my nonsense.

Comment: Not nonsense - we never solved it :( i.e. we still don't know why changing the bundle id made this difference.

Comment: True that. I guess I will just create a new project with proper Bundle ID and transfer everything there. Wouldn't call that a solution tho.